# On Click of Form Reset button , how to clear Jquery Validaton error messages?

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery and bootstrap in combination .
I have got a Form with 2 components a text input and a file input .

**Issue 1 :**

Initially click on Submit button without doing anything in the form
and it doesn't clear the jquery Validation error messages on click of Reset Button .

**Issue 2:**

Enter some description under text input and upload any picture and on click of **RESET** Button it doesn't clear the input type file value .

This is my js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#pacinsertform').validate(
    {
      rules:
      {
        previewpic:
        {
          required: true
        },
        description:
        {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages:
      {
        previewpic:
        {
          required: "Upload Image required",
        },
        description:
        {
          required: "description  required",
        }
      },
      highlight: function(element)
      {
        $(element).parent().addClass('error')
      },
      unhighlight: function(element)
      {
        $(element).parent().removeClass('error')
      },
      submitHandler: function(event, validator)
      {
        if ($("#pacinsertform").valid())
        {
          ajaxInsertPac();
          return false;
        }
      }
    });

});
$("#previewpic").change(function()
                        {
  $("#previewpic").blur().focus();
});



function ajaxInsertPac()
{
  alert('ajax call heer');
  return false;
}
$(document).on("click", ".removepic", function(event)
               {
  $("#previewpic").attr('name', 'previewpic');
});
$(document).on("click", ".resetform", function(event)
               {
  $("#description").val('');
  $("#previewpic").val('');
});
```

This is my fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/48/

Comment: on click on cancel / reset button, you should call the resetForm: https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/, and for me, it is clears the description...

Comment: Thanks , i already tried that , but its not working , this is the fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/50/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue 1 you can use:

```
$("#pacinsertform").validate().resetForm();
```

for reset the form.

For your issue 2 you can fire trigger click remove button like below:

```
$(".removepic").trigger( "click" );
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/55/)

Answer (score 2):

To remove jquery validation message on reset use : `$("label.error").html('');`

To reset file upload control on reset button : `$(".removepic").trigger('click');`

Please check working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/53/